# Delaying function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, delay

I don't have a code to sample or anything, because I have no idea how to do it, but can someone please tell me how to delay a function with swift for a set amount of time?

Comment: You should include things you've tried/looked up. I know the language is fairly new, but it has to have documentation somewhere.

Comment: Not the most legitimate of sources, but give this a look over: http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/28v5pv/wait_function/

Comment: Just a word of advice – there are countless examples of how to do this in Obj-C. If you ever want to be a competent iOS developer, you will need to learn Obj-C, or at least how to translate Obj-C into Swift.

Comment: To name a couple of methods, take a look in the Apple documentation at dispatch_after and NSTimer.

Comment: `sleep(10)` before the method invocation

Comment: ^ No, don't use `sleep(10)`. That will put the entire thread to sleep.

Comment: The best one around [Matt's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/3648310)

Answer (score 460, accepted):

You can use GCD (in the example with a 10 second delay):

### Swift 2

```
let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 10)
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.functionToCall()
})
```

### Swift 3 and Swift 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0, execute: {
    self.functionToCall()
})
```

### Swift 5 or Later

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
        //call any function
 }
```

Comment: GCD stands for "Grand Central Dispatch". Apple define it as: _Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) comprises language features, runtime libraries, and system enhancements that provide systemic, comprehensive improvements to the support for concurrent code execution on multicore hardware in iOS and OS X._ You can find more info [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/)

Comment: What if you wanted to do a fraction of a second say 0.5?

Comment: @CodyWeaver: then you need to change the first line cast to: 

`let triggerTime = (Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 0.5))`

Comment: What's the reason I should use this method and not something like NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(3), target: self, selector: "functionHere", userInfo: nil, repeats: false) ?

Comment: I think the main reason is code locality. All the logic is on the same block. But if you want a repeating block NSTimer is better.

Comment: Where do you get DISPATCH_TIME_NOW

Comment: @DroidChris - If you are trying this code in Swift 3 you need to use DispatchTime.now() - The code in this answer is for Swift 2

Comment: how to call the function on class method , where we can use Self.functioncall() ?

Comment: This, like 99% of answers to the simple question: "how to delay code?" misses the point. The question does not ask how to call another function after a delay, but to simply add a delay a function. Semantics here are everything.

Comment: deadline: .now() + .seconds(10)

Answer (score 38):

**Swift 3 and Above** Version(s) for a delay of 10 seconds

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) { [unowned self] in
        self.functionToCall()
    }
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: { something() })

Comment: WRT the unowned self, I think it is better to declare unowned self in the lambda, e.g.,
`{ [unowned self] in self.functionToCall() }`. That way the class doesn't have an unowned reference that it really doesn't need.

Comment: @sschilli: Thanks for the comment. Updated the code.

Answer (score 24):

```
 NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(3), target: self, selector: "functionHere", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

This would call the function functionHere() with a 3 seconds delay

Comment: how to send argument in that function functionHere()?

Comment: Swift 3 version of this:

Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(3), target: self, selector: "functionHere", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

Answer (score 4):

For adding argument to delay function.

First setup a dictionary then add it as the userInfo. Unwrap the info with the timer as the argument.

```
let arg : Int = 42
let infoDict : [String : AnyObject] = ["argumentInt", arg]

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(3), target: self, selector: "functionHereWithArgument:", userInfo: infoDict, repeats: false)
```

Then in the called function

```
func functionHereWithArgument (timer : NSTimer)
{
    if let userInfo = timer.userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    {
         let argumentInt : Int = (userInfo[argumentInt] as! Int)
    }
}
```