# Execute action of code after certain amount of time in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want an action to be run after 120 seconds but for the rest of the code to continue to run without interruption is there a way to do this in swift? For example

```
var timer = 0
if timer == 120{
print("time up")
}
//But This code still needs to be able to be run
if buttonPressed == true{
 print("pressed")
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/1630618

Comment: With the above `delay` function, you'd do `delay(120) { print("time up") }` which does that in 2 minutes, but the code that follows executes immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821805/6496271

> let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 10)
>   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
>       self.functionToCall()
>   })

It calls self.functionToCall() after 10 seconds

To make it 120 secs:

```
let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 120)
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.functionToCall()
})
```