# Delay Action / Function

Tags: ios, swift, delay

What I am intended to do is that, I have one button which triggers two labels. Two labels are initially hidden. I wanted one to appear right away, and the other seconds later when the button is clicked.

What can I add to make this happen?

```
@IBOutlet var noDelayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var delayLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func delayButton(_ sender: Any) {
    noDelayLabel.isHidden = false
    delayLabel.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821722/delaying-function-in-swift and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func delayButton(_ sender: Any) {
    noDelayLabel.isHidden = false
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + \*delay value here*\}, 
        execute: {
            self.delayLabel.isHidden = false
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Please flag duplicate questions as duplicates instead of answering with duplicate content. This answer already exists all over the place.