# Changing to a Tabbar tab view programmatically in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with 5 view controllers. In my third view controller I have a table view and its didSelect method I am changing my TabBar tab programmatically to a first tab using following code.         `tabBarController?.selectedViewController = tabBarController.childViewControllers[0]`
In my first view controller which is `childViewControllers[0]` there is viewDidAppear method including my ActivityIndicator and some API calls. When I changed my tab bar programmatically using above code third view controller stays on the screen and as soon as viewDidAppear method finishes it is switching which causes sense of freezing to a user . However, when I press directly to first view controller first view controller appearing then, shows Activity Indicator making API calls. What could be the reason of it and how can I solve it?

Comment: add some minor delay for API call which will fix the issue of freeze

Comment: Can you let us know, how are you changing View Controller ?

Comment: Issue of freeze is not about API call. As I said when I pressed first tab bar from the tab bar it is showing my activity indicator and making API call. Problem is when I switch my tab bar programmatically in my didSelectRowAt function it is waiting to finish API call. @Vinodh

Comment: It is but obvious, during API call, UI freezes, so what you want instead of that?

Comment: can you comment the API call and try switching tabbar. If UI not freezing then UI Switching and API call works on same thread which cause the freeze . So delay when switching tabs

Comment: @Vinodh yes when I comment API call it is not freezing. How can I delay it when switching tabs?

Comment: @NilomiShah I need to show something like Activity Indicator user should not wait without any reaction when select something from table view.

Comment: you can use this method to add delay for calling https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821805/1142743. Post notification from third viewcontroller to firstview when didselect is called in listener add API call with delay

Comment: Thanks dude it is now working like a charm. I put my code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` as you said @Vinodh

Comment: post it as answer so other will know the reason for freeze and what is the fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I changed my `tabBarController?.selectedViewController = tabBarController.childViewControllers[0]` code

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
tabBarController?.selectedViewController = tabBarController.childViewControllers[0]
}
```

It works well some API calls in the first view controller are causing to freeze so I put it inside main thread thanks to @Vinodh

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```