# swift: call action several times from array

Tags: ios, swift

I have array with int values:

```
var array = [1,82,17,29,74,94,76,97,48,78,88,20,31]
```

And action:

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        print("i")
    }
```

I want to my action to be called for values in array.

For example: first time action calls after 1 seconds, next time after 82 seconds, and next after 17 seconds. And etc...

How to do it?

Comment: Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821722/delaying-function-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to achieve this.

```
    var count = 0
    let seconds = array[count] // get initial value
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: seconds, target: self, selector: #selector(callMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

@objc func callMethod() {
    print("CallMethod....")
    count += 1
    if count < array.count {
    let nextTime = array[count] // get next time value
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: nextTime, target: self, selector: #selector(callMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
 }
}
```

Comment: `Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue Int'` in this line` count++`

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) in this case. Here you can find how to use timer in swift [Timer Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007862/6634982). In update method of example just reschedule timer with new seconds value.